# How to figure the missing values in dataframe based on other data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to find values that are in a dataframe, and not in another one.
For example I have a dataframe like this:

```
|---------------------|
|      Col1           |
|---------------------|
|         1111        |
|---------------------|
|         2222        |
|---------------------|
|         3333        |
|---------------------|
|         4444        |
|---------------------|
|         5555        |
|---------------------|
|         6666        |
|---------------------|
|         7777        |
|---------------------|
```

and another dataframe like this:

```
|---------------------|
|      Col2           |
|---------------------|
|         1111        |
|---------------------|
|         2222        |
|---------------------|
|         3333        |
|---------------------|
|         4444        |
|---------------------|
```

I want a result something like this

```
|---------------------|
|      missing values |
|---------------------|
|         5555        |
|---------------------|
|         6666        |
|---------------------|
|         7777        |
|---------------------|
```

## Edited

```
esn_datafeed_df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[esn_datafeed]', engine)
esn_inter_intra_merge_df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[esn_inter_intra_merge]', engine)


merged = esn_datafeed_df.merge(esn_inter_intra_merge_df, how='left', indicator=True)
merged.query("_merge == 'left_only'")[["st_umts_df_relation_key"]]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/haroo501/PycharmProjects/tool_check_nbr/my_missing_result.py", line 16, in <module>
    merged = esn_datafeed_df.merge(esn_inter_intra_merge_df, how='left', indicator=True)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\tool_check_nbr\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7336, in merge
    return merge(
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\tool_check_nbr\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 83, in merge
    return op.get_result()
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\tool_check_nbr\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 642, in get_result
    join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\tool_check_nbr\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 859, in _get_join_info
    (left_indexer, right_indexer) = self._get_join_indexers()
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\tool_check_nbr\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 837, in _get_join_indexers
    return _get_join_indexers(
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\tool_check_nbr\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1320, in _get_join_indexers
    return join_func(lkey, rkey, count, **kwargs)
  File "pandas/_libs/join.pyx", line 97, in pandas._libs.join.left_outer_join
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 298. MiB for an array with shape (39003243,) and data type int64
```

How can I solve that?
Hope someone to help me to solve this

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please provide a sample of your input(s) so that we can better understand your issue.

Comment: Please check this question: it is related to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483823/what-is-the-analogue-of-except-clause-in-sql-in-pandas . Basically 'EXCEPT' function does what you are looking for - but EXCEPT function is available in SPARK. You need to find the equivalent function in python.

Comment: @User9102d82 thanks  for your support I tried to `set_index` by using the following code `result = esn_datafeed_df[~esn_datafeed_df.set_index('st_umts_df_relation_key').isin(esn_inter_intra_merge_df.set_index('st_umts_esn_inter_intra_relation_key'))].dropna()`

and found this error `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_index'`

Comment: `@G. Anderson  you mean add tables to explain on it?

Comment: @G.Anderson  Could you please check edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a LEFT JOIN. You can do that using function `merge` in Pandas. Using `indicator=True` lets you see which values are only in one dataframe (as identified by indicator variable `'left_only'`) which is what you were looking for.

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], columns=["my_column"])
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3], columns=["my_column"])
>>> merged = df1.merge(df2, how="left", indicator=True)
>>> merged.query("_merge == 'left_only'")[["my_column"]]

    my_column
3   4
4   5
5   6
```

Comment: I think this works also for me `result = esn_datafeed_df[~esn_datafeed_df.set_index(list(esn_datafeed_df.st_umts_df_relation_key)).index.isin(esn_inter_intra_merge_df.set_index(list(esn_inter_intra_merge_df.st_umts_esn_inter_intra_relation_key)).index)]
`

Comment: This is hardly readable. Using easy variable names like `df1`, `df2` would make things easier for your next question :). By the way, there can be multiple working answers to a question.

Comment: do you have any Idea about this error `TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'tuple'> was passed`, Could you check my edit?

Comment: Sure. You forgot to call function `pd.read_sql()` when defining `esn_inter_intra_merge_df `. 
It should be:
`esn_inter_intra_merge_df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[esn_inter_intra_merge]', engine)`

Comment: Ops I am sorry I didn't take care of that... :D I changed it... but I found another error :( `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 298. MiB for an array with shape (39003243,) and data type int64`

Comment: I think the error speaks for itself. The logic (answer) is good, but your computer is running out of memory because there are > 39M rows in your dataframe. Restart your kernel maybe.

Comment: have the same error also when restart the kernel any way thanks alot for your support